# Is using enums safe in all compilers?

Tags: c, compiler-construction

In a discussion, a colleague told me that he never uses `enum` because he experienced that **some** C-compilers don't cope with the `enum` statement correctly.

He couldn't remember which compiler exactly had problems but among the problems, there were errors when doing something like

```
enum my_enum{
  my_enum_first  = 5;
  my_enum_second = 10;
};
```

i.e. initializing enum values instead of letting the compiler do the automatic assignment. Another one was that the compiler decides for itself how big the enum is and therefore you could have unpredictable behavior for `sizeof my_enum` when compiling your code under various platforms.

To get around that, he told me to better use `#define`s to define the constant elements. But especially for using doxygen it's quite handy to have an enum (e.g. as function parameter) because in the generated documentation, you could simply click on `my_enum` and directly jump to the description of `my_enum`.

Another example would be code completion, where your IDE tells you what you could specify as valid parameters for functions. I know that – as long as you're compiling the code as C-code – that there's no type-safety (i.e. I could also specify `5` instead of `my_enum_first`), so the use of an `enum` seems to be a more cosmetic thing.

**The question is:** do you know any compilers that have limitations regarding the usage of `enum`?

---

**Edit 1:**
Regarding the environment: we are developing for various embedded platforms, so there *could* also be a compiler for some *obscure micro-controller*...

---

**Edit 2:**
He could tell me that the *KEIL C51* compiler didn't play well with enums. Are there any experiences with current versions of the *C51* compiler?

Comment: Maybe you should ask your coworker which year it was he had this problem... or if it was for some obscure micro-controller.

Comment: :-) He could tell me that it was "some years ago"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that a compiler that doesn't play nice with enum is an invalid compiler - enum is specified in the standard, so a failure to implement it means the compiler shouldn't technically be used to compile C (For the record, the scope of enumeration types is discussed in 6.2.1 and defined as a type in 6.2.5 (of C99), so one would assume that it's a valid part of the standard from thereon in)!
So no, I don't know of any such compilers.

Answer (score 5):

Compilers are free to choose the size of an enum based on its range of possible values. This only really becomes an issue if you're exposing enums in your API, and users of your code may be using a different compiler or build options.

In this case, confusion can be caused by the calling code passing in a 16-bit value, for example, and the receiving code expecting it to be 32 bits. If the top 16 bits of the passed-in value are left uninitialized, then bad things will happen.

You can work around this kind of issue by including a dummy entry in your enum to enforce a minimum size.

For example:

```
typedef enum {
    FirstValue = 12,
    SecondValue = 25,

    DummyValue = 65536  // force enum to be greater than 16 bits
} MyEnum;
```